# String-length in the M4 preprocessor

Tags: m4, text-manipulation

So, with this simple input,

```
define(foo, len($1)) foo(abcdef)
```

I get, as output:

```
 2
```

How can I get this to print `5`, instead? I can't figure out any combination of quoting that makes `len()` actually receive *the value of `$1`, `abcdef`*, instead of the literal string `` `$1' ``.

**Edit 1:** The actual code in question looks something like this:

```
define(`FILE', `#' /!\ $1 /!\
`#' ====substr(==============================,0,len($1))====)dnl
FILE(`UTILITY.ASM')
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what this has to do with [c], its [c-preprocessor], or [preprocessor]s in general (m4 is a general-purpose macro language / macro processor).  Please update your question either to show how it is related to those tags or to remove those tags.

Comment: M4 is usually suggested (often on SO!) as a replacement for people trying to do do complex things with the CPP. I'm leaving the tags, as it seems that, pragmatically speaking, any M4 question is an extension of a CPP question; but I won't be offended if someone wishes to remove them. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The under-quoting of `len($1)` leads to its immediate evaluation during the define step so foo is defined as 2.

I.e. this is equivalent to:

```
define(foo, 2) foo(abcdef)
```

When full quoting, the results are what you are expecting:

```
define(`foo', `len($1)') foo(`abcdef')
> 6
```